# JavaCV: OpenCVFrameGrabber doesn't start

Tags: javacv

short version: my grabber doesn't start

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0, Java JDK and javacv.

My problem is, that i switch between two cameras. One is from my robot and I access it with "IPCameraFrameGrabber("..."). **This part works fine**, but for debugging (and mobility) purposes i want to test the code with my laptop camera (OpenCVFrameGrabber(0) or (-1)...testet both, same result). yet it seems grabber.start(); doesn't start.

I use following code (simplified but I think the basics are included, are they?)

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage;

public class Simple_camera_test {

IplImage imgBin;
static IplImage imgGrab;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    System.out.println("Cam check");

    grabber.start();
    System.out.println("grabber started");

    imgGrab = grabber.grab();

    CanvasFrame canvasFrame2 = new CanvasFrame("Cam2");
    canvasFrame2.setCanvasSize(imgGrab.width(), imgGrab.height());
    //canvasFrame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    grabber.setFrameRate(30);

    while ((imgGrab = grabber.grab()) != null){

        canvasFrame2.showImage(imgGrab);


        cvReleaseImage(imgGrab);

    }
    grabber.stop();
    canvasFrame2.dispose();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

When I run the code it prints "Cam check" and the cameralight begins to glow, but then for the next 2-3 minutes nothing happens. after that the output is:

```
run:
Cam check
    (after 2-3 min pause - exception handling)
grabber started
com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: cvRetrieveFrame() Error: Could not retrieve frame. (Has start() been called?)
at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.grab(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:236)
at simple_camera_test.Simple_camera_test.main(Simple_camera_test.java:29)
```

So for me the problem is "grabber doesn't" start, but until now I'm not able to get it to start. Maybe my assumption is wrong in general...Can anyone help me with this matter? As said, IPCameraFrameGrabber(robot-ip) works fine with exact the same code.

If you need further informations please let me know.

I'm sorry for my english, but thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out that it's a camera issue. On an other Laptop my code works fine, but if anyone has a hint, how i can get my camera back to work, it would be nice, too!

It's the integrated camera of a lenovo twist 64bit, win8.1 and the issue is: if started (due programm-code or programms like skype) the green light glows but no image appears.
I already tried lenovo settings (cam not on private), new drivers, de- and reinstalling.

I don't really expect a answer on that, but if anyone coincidentally had this issue before and has a solution, please let me know! It could spare me some time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
CvCapture capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
    IplImage frame= cvQueryFrame(capture);      
    cvNamedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    char c = 0;
    while( c!=27 && frame!=null;) {
        frame= cvQueryFrame(capture);           
        cvShowImage("Video", frame);            
        c= (char )cvWaitKey(30);            
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Video");
```